# Using filter on a JSON object for items that include a string

Tags: javascript, jquery

First off, I have searched low and high for questions regarding filtering json objects by strings that contain substrings, but have only found ones regarding strings that equal strings. I want to filter the objects by what the name attribute contains. So if a user types in the string "Smith", it would pull the second object(Jane Smith). The problem with my code is that it always displays ALL objects regardless of what is typed into the input.

Here's my code so far:

```
people = [
  {
    name: "John Doe",
    age: 24,
    sex: "male"
  },
  {
    name: "Jane Smith",
    age: 28,
    sex: "female"
  }
];

$('#search').on('input', function(el) {
  $('ul').empty()
  $(people).filter(function(k, person){
    return person.name.includes($(el).value)
  })

  $(people).each(function(k, person){
    $('ul').append(
      $('<li></li>').text(person.name)
    )
  })
})
```

What am I doing wrong?

Answer (score -1, accepted):

At line `$('#search').on('input', function(el) {` el is not a selector for jQuery and you need to use `el.target.value` to get the input.

Filter will return an array so if you run `each` on the filterd array you need to save the filtered data in a variable `let peopleNames = [];` else you just run on the original array.
also i've added toLowerCase() but you don't have to

```js
people = [
  {
    name: "John Doe",
    age: 24,
    sex: "male"
  },
  {
    name: "Jane Smith",
    age: 28,
    sex: "female"
  }
];
let peopleNames = [];
$('#search').on('input', function(el) {
  $('ul').empty()
  peopleNames = $(people).filter(function(k, person){
    return person.name.toLowerCase().includes(el.target.value)
  })
  $(peopleNames).each(function(k, person){
    $('ul').append(
      $('<li></li>').text(person.name)
    )
  })
})
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<input type="text" id="search" />
<ul></ul>
```

Answer (score 2):

The [`filter`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/filter) method of `Array` returns the filtered array.

```
const regex = new RegExp( YOUR_STRING, 'gi');

const people = [
  {
    name: "John Doe",
    age: 24,
    sex: "male"
  },
  {
    name: "Jane Smith",
    age: 28,
    sex: "female"
  }
];

const rv = people.filter(
  record => record.name.match(regex)
);

console.log(rv);
```

Comment: Now its displaying no results with this https://jsfiddle.net/kzL8rjoa/2/

Comment: @ShoeLace1291: That's a new question I think: for one, you are not creating a new regex properly, `new RegExp($(el).value, 'g')` -- no need for the `/`, and the flags are the second param to that method. Check MDN for details.

Comment: An easy solution in pure JS to filter a value from a property of an array of objects in json.

Answer (score 0):

The jQuery [.filter()](https://api.jquery.com/filter/) function **returns** a new jQuery object with the filter applied. So, you must call [.each()](https://api.jquery.com/jquery.each/) on this new object, instead of calling it on `$(people)` again.

Also, `$(el).value` should be `$(el.target).val())`, since `el` is a [jQuery event object](https://api.jquery.com/category/events/event-object/) and not a DOM element.

```
people = [
  {
    name: "John Doe",
    age: 24,
    sex: "male"
  },
  {
    name: "Jane Smith",
    age: 28,
    sex: "female"
  }
];

$('#search').on('input', function(el) {
  $('ul').empty()
  $(people).filter(function(k, person){
    return person.name.includes($(el.target).val())
  }).each(function(k, person){
    $('ul').append(
      $('<li></li>').text(person.name)
    )
  })
})
```

Comment: Hmm now it doesnt seem to display any results https://jsfiddle.net/kzL8rjoa/1/

Comment: I edited the answer. I forgot I had modified your code for testing!